# Event driven architecture in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, event

I'm trying to create an automated trigger event (Postgres is my main DB) on something like this:

```
Orders table
----------------
Order_Expiry_Date: Date
Customer_email: String
```

When as soon as `expiry_date` is about to be lapsed, or has lapsed, I want to trigger an email to the `customer_email` notifying them of this. Yes, I understand one simple approach is to have a daily cron job that monitors this and acts accordingly.

I know nothing of message queues, event driven architecture, etc. How would I go about a) having postgres automatically trigger some action that initiates an API call when `current date + 15 days > order_expiry_date`? If there's a good place to learn about this, please let me know!

Comment: You cannot do that in PostgreSQL.

Comment: OK - so how would i :)

Comment: You have to write a program that is driven from an operating system scheduler like `cron`.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Was hoping to avoid that. Thanks!